# How to know the method that hangs in .net process built on release

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have the dump files of a .net process that hangs in an unknown location.  I need to know the method where the hang is occurring.  The application is very complex with many threads, and the hang occurs randomly.

When it happens on my machine or the client's machine I have tried to attach visual studio, but I couldn't get to the hanging method.  Are there any tools to investigate the problem in the dump files?

**EDIT**
The hanging thread is the main UI thread.  Other threads are working because they log their activities.

Comment: Is it hanging, or going into an infinite loop and eating processor time?

Comment: I am not sure, but the processor is 50%, but there are many threads other than the UI thread.

Comment: On a multi-core machine, you can make Task Manager show each core separately. If one core is at 100%, then it's likely an infinite loop in your UI thread.

Comment: It is not correct, try an infinite loop, in a simple console app, it won't make only one core take 100%, the load is on all the cores. I am trying on i7 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have memory dumps, you can analyze them with Windbg.   For a great tutorial on using Windbg to diagnose hangs, refer to Tess Fernandez's blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-lab-1-hang.aspx).

If this is an app you have built, you should build the Release configuration with debug symbols as well.  This can help greatly down the road when debugging situations like this.

Comment: I have dump files without "debug symbols" :( how can i debug that?